# Loading Angular component that was already loaded by routerLink

Tags: angular

If a page or component is already loaded by a user clicking a routerLink in the main menu, how can I repeat same process if a user clicks that router link again? Clicking a router link that has already been clicked has no effect.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">        
    <li class="nav-item" id="signup-link"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="signup">Sign up</a></li>
    ...
```

Comment: what effect did you expect?

Comment: load component again, i'd like the component to load again

Comment: what do you mean load?

Comment: kind of like a page refresh, i just want the url to go back to its initial state

Comment: Isn't `location.reload();` a right thing to use in the scenario?
Actually question is not clear enough to know why that is to write an answer

Comment: probably would do, thought there might be something angulary. i'll have to add some logic to the code if i use location.reload though

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to call a function when the `li` component is being clicked and in that function you will reinitialize the component's properties.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">        
    <li (click)="reInit()" class="nav-item" id="signup-link"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="signup">Sign up</a></li>
    ...
```

And the component file:

```
@Component({
        ....
});
export class MyComponent {
        private property;
        reInit() { // this will reinitialize property
            this.property = null; // or 0 or [] etc.
        }

        setProperty(value) { // this will alter property
            this.property = value;
        }
        ...
}
```